# If $\overline{x}$ is a point such that $f(x)=f(\overline{x}) \Rightarrow$ $x$ is a local minimizer, then $\overline{x}$ is global minimizer

Tags: real-analysis

> Suppose that $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous
> function.
>
> Let $\overline{x}$ be a point that satisfies the following:
> If $x$ is such that $f(x)=f(\overline{x})$, then $x$ is
> a local minimizer. Prove that $\overline{x}$ is a global minimizer of $f$.

My attempt:

By contradiction, let's assume that exists a point $y$ such $f(y)<f(\overline{x})$.

I'm trying to prove that there exists $z$ such that $f(z) = f(\overline{x})$ but $z$ is not a local minimizer.
I defined the set $A = \{x: f(x) < f(\overline{x})\}$. $A$ is open since $f$ is continuous  and nonempty by the contradiction hypothesis. I'm trying to build a sequence $z_k$ in $A$ that converges to a point $z$ such that $f(z) = f(\overline{x})$. If I'm able to prove it, then we can conclude that $z$ is not a local minimizer.
However, I'm not able to prove it.
I'm not sure either if I should use another topological property.

I appreciate any help or hints.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you correctly said, $A = \{x: f(x) < f(\overline{x})\}$ is an open set.

The given condition implies that $B = \{x: f(x) \ge f(\overline{x})\}$ is open as well:

- If $f(x) = f(\overline{x})$ then $x$ is a local minimizer, so that a neighborhood of $x$ is contained in $B$.
- And if $f(x) > f(\overline{x})$ then the same is true because of the continuity of $f$.

Since $\Bbb R^n$ is connected, one of the sets must be empty.