# Global Minimizer.

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima, connectedness

I find the following thread
[If $\overline{x}$ is a point such that $f(x)=f(\overline{x}) \Rightarrow$ $x$ is a local minimizer, then $\overline{x}$ is global minimizer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3838912/if-overlinex-is-a-point-such-that-fx-f-overlinex-rightarrow-x-is?rq=1)

I am  trying to understand the solution, I understand that the target is prove that the set $A=\emptyset$ and use that $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is connected. but I do not  understand, why the set $B$ is open? and the affirmation:  And if $f(x) > f(\overline{x})$ then the same is true because of the continuity of $f$.

Could someone help me?. Thanks!

Comment: (1) If $f(x) = f(\bar{x})$, then $x$ is a local minimizer and thus there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $f(y) \ge f(x) = f(\bar{x})$ for all $y$ in $(x - \delta, x + \delta)$ (the definition of local minimizer). In other words, $(x - \delta, x + \delta) \subseteq B$.
(2) If $f(x) > f(\bar{x})$, blablabla

According to the definition of open set, $B$ is open.

Comment: Thanks! I want to write my attempt. 1. A is open. $A=f^{-1}(\infty,f(\overline{x}))$, since $f$ is continuous. A is open. 2. A is closed.  If $x \in \overline{A}$, there exists $\{x^{k}\}\subset A$,s.t. $x^{k}\to x$ when $k\to \infty$, since $x \in \overline{A}$, $\lim_{k \to \infty}f(x^{k})<f(\overline{x})$, so  $f(x)<f(\overline{x})$, thus $x \in A$. It works. Thank you in advance.